# Fixed points of Gauss Transformation

Tags: dynamical-systems

Gauss Transformation defined as $\psi(x):[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ 
defined  as
$\psi(x)=
      \frac{1}{x}-\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\rfloor, 0 < x\leq 1  $ and $0$ for $x=0$ 
I want to find fixed points for this transformation. Clearly $x=0$ is a fixed point. With the help of graph we can see infinite number of fixed points as its intersects with $y=x$ in infinite number if times.
if $x\neq 0$  then $\psi(x)=x$ 
$\frac{1}{x}-\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\rfloor = x$ 
$\frac{1}{x}-x=\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\rfloor $ 
How to solve this ?
The grpah is [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Restrict $x$ to the interval $(1/(n+1), 1/n]$ to evaluate $\lfloor 1/x \rfloor$.

Comment: Ya got it. Thank you Sam Freedman

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept the answer so others know the question has been resolved.